# Congratulations, DonAntonio!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

I'm all for another occasion to *celebrate*.  [DonAntonio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31254/donantonio) has surpassed $100$k today!

Congratulations, DonAntonio, for this impressive accomplishment!

And just as important, *thank you* for your time, your long-standing dedication to this site, and your $4300 +$ answers (and, of course, your classic comments)!

Comment: IMO, @DonAntonio is one of the most impressive contributors on M.SE. Congratulations! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: Don Antonio helped me ace my comprehensive exams for complex and linear analysis

Comment: Thanks for all your contribution, Don Antonio (づ｡◕‿‿◕｡)づ ♥

Comment: Congrats! And that in only 2 years and 1 month! Keep up the good work.

Comment: Strange that he passed the 100k mark 10 weeks ago, but without any bounties, he managed to get his reputation a couple thousand points less.

Comment: @G.T.R Now it's accurate again.

Comment: @Asaf Consequence of a suspension due to [voting irregularities.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16203637#16203637) Simultaneously [Timbuc](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/118527/timbuc) was suspended also for a week, and also lost much rep.

Comment: @Bill: Last night when I saw that, for some reason I read "Jul 8" on the timestamp of this post, and I was surprised since there were no serious reputation deducts from July till now. But now I notice that this is actually June and not July, and indeed in late-middle June there is a deduction of over 2500 points.

Comment: After DonAntonio another "[big name](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy)" (guess who?) is now suspended for voting irregularities. This tends to become suspicious and makes other users think about how high rep users gain their rep points.

Comment: Hi, debating of the process of suspension is not about me, clearly Deepsea has things to say about that, and anyway his thread is fcked up by the 30 downvotes.

Comment: @user26857 Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @tatan Don't think you are a little late to the party?

Comment: @user26857 Nah... just asking...

Answer (score 36):

I will wish you, on the behalf of all the M.SE users, a big
$$\Large{\text{Congratulations, @DonAntonio!}}\\
\large{\text{Thanks for all your contributions!}}\\
\text{- the M.SE Community}$$

Answer (score 6):

I love your answers @DonAntonio , You've helped me alot!

Thank you!!!